# Do I need explicit permissions to clone the FB login page for teaching and demonstration purposes?

Tags: copyright, ethical-hacking

We are in the business of training on Ethical Hacking. One of our modules shows a demo of the Social Engineering Toolkit. The demo involves cloning of the Facebook login page. One of our members felt that we needed explicit permissions from FB to go ahead with it. I am not sure about this. This makes it difficult to do many demos as each demo would require some permission or the other. Need advise on how to approach this.

Comment: Is it necesarry to clone it for a demonstration? Cant you make a near clone with a different brand name or something?

Comment: As written, it is a request for legal advice. Which is out of bounds. Get a lawyer.